# Как вывести дату регистрации?

Tags: php, mysql

Как я заметил, дату регистрации сохраняют с помощью time();

Как это число превратить в человеческий вид?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это число называется timestamp и показывает количество секунд, прошедших с начала эпохи Unix (1970г.) Перевести timestamp в различные форматы даты можно функцией [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php)

Comment: Сам нашел уже. Все так проще, чем я думал). Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вариант №1: Писать в базу изначально читабельную дату

```
$date = date('d.m.Y H:i');
```

[Описание функции](http://php.su/functions/?date)

Вариант №2: Преобразовывать timestamp с помощью той же date.

```
$date = date('d.m.Y H:i', $sql['date']);
```

Answer (score 0):

достать это число из базы и с помощью функции [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) превратить в человеческий вид

Answer (score -1):

Есть такое - DATE_FORMAT.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(RegDate,"%e.%m.%y") as RegDate From users Where userid = 1
```

Comment: Какой-то странный способ. То, что мне нужно - date()